# Input type password field wasn't submitted with Enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, form-submit, redux-form

i have a redux-form with two input fields, the first one is of type text and the second is of type password. You can see the code here:

```
<div className="input-box">
            <Field
              id="username"
              name="username"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
              component={inputField}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="input-box">
            <Field
              id="password"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              component={inputField}
            />
```

I've also add validators to the container like this:

```
const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};

  if (!values.get('username')) {
    errors.username = 'Username is required';
  }
  if (!values.get('password')) {
    errors.password = 'Password is required';
  }
  return errors;
};
```

My problem is that when i press the Enter button even if the password field is filled the validator for the password is triggered. When i click the button which has type submit the form is submitted successfully. Why is that?

Comment: I've tried reproducing your issue, but so far I've been unable to. Do you have a working bin on http://www.webpackbin.com (or similar) that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont. I remove the type password and the form is working correctly. Is it a bug of redux-form?